# OnClickListener vs. RelativeLayout.OnClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-relativelayout

I am following some tutorials for how to implement listeners, and find that some are using the RelativeLayout.OnClickListener and others just the OnClickListener. I haven't found any documentation explaining the difference between the two.

Is the method of RelativeLayout just altered to include additional functionality for layouts? What is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

For the purpose of view click listeners, there's only `View.OnClickListener`.

If you import the `android.view.View.OnClickListener` inner class, you can use it without specifying the outer `View` class.

If you specify a class that derives from `View` such as `RelativeLayout`, you can also use it to specify the inner class to use.

(There's also `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` but you use it only with dialogs.)

Comment: Thank you! I was aware of RelativeLayout deriving from View, but didn't put the pieces together.

Answer (score 0):

No, RelativeLayout.OnClickListener comes from [View.OnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) as RelativeLayout extends View.

So you could use both, even though eclipse will maybe warn to to use the latter instead.

There is another OnClickListener: [DialogInterface.OnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnClickListener.html) used for Dialog